# Java stream based on condition create list

Tags: java, java-stream

Below code returns [Test11, Test33, Test44]. But I want is [Test11, Test2, Test33, Test44]. i.e When realName exists use it, else use the altName.

The line which i commented out is giving correct result. But getRealName method is being called twice.
Is there any way to use the stream() to get the desired output that i want without calling the method twice? Please help.

```
public class Main {
    private static HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myMap.put("Test11", "Test1");
        myMap.put("Test33", "Test3");
        myMap.put("Test44", "Test4");

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Test1");
        list.add("Test2");
        list.add("Test3");
        list.add("Test4");


        List<String> result = list.stream().map(altName -> getRealName(altName)).
                filter(realName ->  Objects.nonNull(realName)).collect(Collectors.toList());

       /* List<String> result = list.stream()
                .map(altName -> getRealName(altName)!=null?getRealName(altName):altName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());*/

        System.out.println(result);

    }

    private static String getRealName(String item) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(item)) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if your `Map` were the right way around?

Comment: If you get it the right way around, it's as simple as `list.stream().map(altName -> myMap.getOrDefault(altName, altName)).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the result of `getRealName` in a variable before doing the logic:

```java
List<String> result = list.stream()
    .map(altName -> {
        var realName = getRealName(altName);
        return realName != null ? realName : altName;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If `getRealName` instead returned an `Optional<String>`, then you could use the `.orElse` method on it:

```java
List<String> result = list.stream()
    .map(altName -> getRealName(altName).orElse(altName)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

By the way, it looks like you should turn your `Map` around (swap keys and values), because you are only querying it by the value. Maps are much more efficient and ergonomic if you query them by the key. Your `getRealName`-method would just be `map.get(altname)`.

Comment: Thank you, first solution worked for me, also changing as getRealName method :)